# How to deal with Chinese Windows path/filename?

Tags: files-and-directories, windows, character-encoding, unicode

I've encountered a problem with Unicode Windows file name.

If I set the file name to Unicode characters on Mac OSX, it works well. But on Windows if the filename starts with a digital number or the filename/path contains Unicode characters, it will not work well. (I am using Chinese Windows version, and Windows may be using GBK codings.)

If the filename starts with a digit, the `\` will `escape` the following digit.

If the filename/path contains a Unicode character, *Mathematica* will not find the file in some situations.

This works:

[image]

This does not work (it tells me the file cannot be found):

[image]

Sorry the pictures are captured using Mac (it works), as on Windows system, the path separator will not be `/` but be `\` . So it will cause the problem mentioned above.

Btw, I am using this to get the filename.

[image]

### Edited

Sorry for late. I managed to find a Windows PC and got the file name as a string.

Here is the Unicode file name on Windows:

```
ExcelFileName
```

> "C:\Users\jinyongjie\Desktop\20161228合纵科技并购.xlsx"

@Stitch I tried to replace the directory separator, but still cannot work:

```
StringReplace[ExcelFileName,"\\"->"/"]
```

> "C:/Users/jinyongjie/Desktop/20161228合纵科技并购.xlsx"

[image]

Comment: are you using ``\\`` or ``\`` on windows?

Comment: Windows generated `\\` as separator automatically.

Comment: So have you tried escaping the backslash? In other words, you'll use "\\" as the path separator in Mathematica.

Comment: is your problem :`FileNameSetter` does not generate double slash for filenames, and that caused file not found problems in some cases?

Comment: It caused file not found.

Comment: You should be able to use `/` on Windows as well.

Comment: For example `StringReplace[fname, "\\" -> "/"]`

Comment: Really? I'll try it. But what about the unicode thing? Windows may encode the filenames as GBK characters so if the filename contains Unicode characters, it will not find the file. How to solve this?

Comment: can you post the file name as a string that we can use to create a file that you can't open?

Comment: Have you considered using `FileNameJoin[]` to construct the full path of the file?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I've tried that. I've tried using `FileNameJoin` and `$PathnameSeparator`. Still cannot open the file.

Comment: @cmal Please try the methods suggested in this thread: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143953/280

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the encoding of file names on Windows systems is "CP936".

To Replace `\` to `/` does not work maybe because of the encoding of `/` is "UTF8", so I use the following expression to split filename to table of strings and then join them back again and intercept them with `$PathnameSeparator`.

```
StringJoin[Riffle[FileNameSplit[Excel文件名], $PathnameSeparator]]
```

And It works!

Comment: Will `FileNameJoin @ FileNameSplit[Excel文件名]` do the same?

Comment: I've tried that. No.